# The etymology of "Alvalade" and its meaning

Tags: significado, etimologia, palavra-para-ideia

It seems Alvalade is not just a [place in Lisbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvalade_%28Lisbon%29): it's an old word for a [walled square or field](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/alvalade).

The word itself does not resemble **wall** (*muro* / *muralha* / *parede*) but it resembles **valley** (*vale*) and **to side** (*ladear*), thus my curiosity. What is the etymology of this word?

It's interesting to notice that there is a [football stadium](http://www.stadiumguide.com/josealvalade/) in this place... Is there any remote chance that the name of the place may have derived from its existence or from a previous walled field?

Comment: Your question asks about the meaning.  The body of the question mentions etymology.  Can you fix that?

Comment: @Centaurus edited. I'd like to understand why the word has that meaning, that's why I left both words/tags.

Comment: I've never heard this word.

Comment: @Centaurus Neither had I, except as a place name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Porto Editora’s Infopédia the [common noun *alvalade*](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/alvalade) comes from the Portuguese *vala* or *valado*, ultimately from the Latin *vallare*, or to defend with trenches, whereas the [place name *Alvalade*](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/toponimia/Alvalade), freguesia de Lisboa and [*Alvalade* in Alentejo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvalade_(Santiago_do_Cac%C3%A9m)), comes from Arabic *al balat*, meaning *plain* as in flat ground. There are various places in Spain named [*Albalat*, and the origin given here](http://heraldica.levante-emv.com/albalat/) is the same, but they say *al-balat* means *path*; The Dicionario de la Real Academia Española says stone-paved path.

As a common noun *alvalade* appears not to be in use anymore. [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/alvalade) lists it as *antigo* (ancient), and Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa does not list it at all. According to Infopédia [*alvalade*](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/alvalade) means *campo ou pátio murado* (walled field or yard). This is pretty much meaning 2 of [*valado*](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/valado)

> 1 Vala, sebe ou elevação de terra que cerca uma propriedade. (Trench or ditch, hedge or fence, embankment, surrounding a piece of land.)
>
> 2 Propriedade rústica cercada por vala, sebe ou elevação. (Piece of land so surrounded.)
>
> Past participle of the verb [*valar*](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/valar) (dig a trench in, surround with a trench). Related to [*vala*](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/vala) (ditch, trench).

In Spanish there is the word [*balate*](http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=5KQF9fuxpDXX2q7PLRGg%7ChkZsNtNbUDXX2nRd3RQX), the meaning of which (embankment, slope, edge of a ditch) closely resembles meaning 1 of *valado*, and comes from Arabic *al-balat*.

So, my best guess is that in former times the two words, *valado* and *alvalade*, similar in meaning to begin with, merged their meanings, and then *alvalade* was forgotten as a common noun and survived as a place name only.

The name Alvalade in Lisbon appears to be very old, for the confrontation that took place there between King D. Dinis and the Crown Prince Afonso (future King D. Afonso IV) in 1323 is known as [Battle de Alvalade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalha_de_Alvalade). No battle took place though, thanks to the last-ditch conciliatory efforts by the wife and mother of the belligerents.